# an esoteric matchbox

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, matches

Seeing a vast repository of [matchstick](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matches) puzzles, Professor Moriarty determined to create one of his own. Behold, his greatest crime yet, the best and worst matches puzzle to ever grace this earth with its presence. **Move as few matches as you can to make another equation that is still true.** (Turning the = into ≠ is frowned upon.)

[image]

By the way, this is read as this (or if you want to be like @Someone, it can be read as something else):
$$\int x \, dx = \frac{x^2}2 +C$$

Note: If you wish to move more than the minimum matchsticks, or do something cool/interesting, that may be acceptable as well.

If you want the link to the primitive Google Slideshow I used to create the graphic, you can make a copy of the slideshow and manipulate the puzzle much more easily, either for your own answer or just to mess with it in a more concrete way.
The slideshow is [here](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1M1jINe9jc1edl_9eBxU2jkiTFbhcSFL_liYaZPTXHsM/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: It looks as though I don't have to move any matches (or if I have to move one I can move it just slightly) and the equation is true. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I have made an edit. The goal is to create a new equation that is still true, by moving as few matchsticks as possible.

Comment: The integral looks like an eighth note…is it possible to use that?

Comment: @Someone Lol, sure

Comment: The left side's an eighth note double-sharped followed by a quarter note double-sharped. Not so sure about the right…

Comment: @Someone the first term on the right is an arpeggio.

Comment: Maybe the second is common time? (what kind of arpeggio?)

Comment: I suppose you must have the same number of sticks, not broken, bent, or obsuring another.

Comment: I wonder why rot13(*gur zngpurf ner fb pnershyyl neenatrq rkprcg sbe bar zngpu bs gur yrggre q*).

Comment: @Weather Vane To your first comment, yes (unless you can create something really cool). For your second comment, I believe that is trivial (no hidden puzzle or anything).

Comment: Please don't close this puzzle. I like it :)

Comment: If I turn the = into - and the + into ≠, is that also frowned upon?

Comment: Depends. Using a ≠ can make it too easy, and can be a kind of cop-out way to "technically" solve the puzzle.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using the same equation (as other answers), by moving

> **One match** from `+` and add to `C`.
>  $\int x \, dx = \frac{x^2}2 - t $

Second attempt: I have moved

> **3 matchsticks**
>
>  [image]
>
>  $$\int x^6 \, dx = \frac{x^7}{7} - C$$

First attempt: I have moved

> **8 matchsticks**
>
>  [image]
>
>  $$\int \frac{1}{x} \, dx = \ln |x| +C$$

Comment: you can also move the top of the C to make it +L, just one match. Or make it +Z.

Comment: I like your 3-matches $x^7$ solution. The 1-match $+t$ solution just begs the question "what is variable $t$?". The original $+C$ equation is self-explanatory because the integral is indefinite and it's a well-known convention that $C$ means "any constant", but there is no such convention for $t$.

Comment: @Stef I could have changed it to `F` but that has a function. I only posted that 1-match solution because apparently, minor changes to the original equation are acceptable :)

Answer (score 10):

How about only moving

> 1 matchstick?

> It's kind of a trivial solution, but:
>
>  [image: a bunch of matchsticks, arranged to form the following equation]
>
>  or, $$\int x \, dx = \frac{1x^2}2 -C$$

Comment: Is that "another equation"?

Comment: I think that's up for op to decide, but I would argue it's equivalent but distinct. I do like both of your solutions tho

Comment: It's creative, and appears different, it counts!

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

> 2 matchsticks - I removed one matchstick to get a minus, and rotated another one to get an equals sign. If you want, the removed matchstick can be placed anywhere to double a line. [image]

> $$\int x \, dx - \frac{x^2}2 = C$$